# Where does Android get these email addresses from?

Tags: email, auto-fill

In an app called Wirex an email autofill appeared. This is very confusing to me. The list contains very old emails, emails I had already forgotten 2 years ago.

I bought this phone in 2018. Where does Android grab these email suggestion from? These are all emails I created so no random email from contact lists.

Comment: I've had something similar happen to me before, though I do not recall the app that was doing this. But I scoured my google contacts and to try and figure it out to no avail.

Comment: Check what is the app's package name?

Answer (score 1):

I found where they came from. I traced those emails to my google account. Basically they were stored as login information (chrome autofill)